# Why am I getting TypeError: 'module' object is not callable using tkinter Fonts

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a Python desktop application using Tkinter GUI.
 This is its code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import random
import time
import datetime
import tkinter.messagebox
import tkinter.font as Font


# Define Font
titleFont = Font(family="Arial", size="48")
```

I am just struggling to think of how this error is being caused:

When I run `titleFont = Font(family="Arial", size="48")`, I get:

> TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing the `tkinter.font` module (as `Font`) and are trying to call it. But Python modules are not callable. I think you are trying to import `Font` **from** the `tkinter.font` module.

Note, that you must create a root window at first.

Here is the revised code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.font import Font


# Define Font
root = Tk()  # create the root window
root.title("Hello, World!")  # set the title of the root window
titleFont = Font(family="Arial", size="48")  # create the Font object (don't forget to specify its master!)
Label(root, text="Hello, World!", font=titleFont).pack()  # create a label to preview the font
root.mainloop()  # start the root window's mainloop
```

Comment: passing `master` to `Font` is optional. It defaults to the root window.